# Load custom class automatically in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

This is in Laravel 5.
I have a custom class in file:

```
app/MyModels/MyVar.php
```

the file contains:

```
<?php
namespace App\MyModels;
class MyVar {
    public static $myIP ="1.2.3.4"; 
}
```

if I want to call the class I have to do this:

first to include it with:

```
use \App\MyModels\MyVar;
```

and then

```
echo MyVar::$myIP;
```

or just to do this without **use**

```
echo \App\MyModels\MyVar::$myIP;
```

What I have to do so I be able to call my class only with its name:

```
echo MyVar::$myIP;
```

without need to use **use** or full path to the class everytime

Maybe I have to put this code somewhere in my app

```
use \App\MyModels\MyVar;
```

so `MyVar` class to work in any file (to be autoloaded). Of course I will be carefull with class names to avoid duplicated classes.

Comment: That's not autoloading. That's how Object Oriented languages *work*. The autoloading happens from PSR-4 and composer, resulting in you not having to write `require` or `include` statements. When dealing with namespaces, it's imperative that you define everything through the `use` keyword, or its fully-qualified name. If you *really* want to avoid declaring your Model(s), inject them as dependencies into a master Controller from which all of your other controllers extend.

Comment: To further clarify, the `use` keyword isn't loading anything. It's merely defining the class you're attempting to leverage, and the namespace in which it resides.

Comment: OK, maybe autoloading is not the exact term, but the idea is to avoid ``use`` because it it the same as using ``include`` (I mean it is extra work). I tried to inject it in the master controller, it is not working.

Comment: As a developer that started learning php structured almost 10 years ago, I absolutely have to say that `use` is so not the same as `include`/`require`

Comment: @vinsa No, it is nothing even close to the same thing. It is a completely unrelated language construct. You're having problems loading in new classes, likely because you forgot to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: And there is exactly *zero* extra work being done by using `use`. Where did you hear about this?

Comment: I mean extra writing of code, so you have to add
``use \App\MyModels\MyVar;`` or ``include('App\MyModels\MyVar.php')``
in any file where I want to use MyVar class, I don't want that, I want to use the class directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `alias` for the class in `aliases` array found in `config/app.php`.

Open the file `config/app.php` and add the following to the end of the `aliases` array.

```
'MyVar' => 'App\MyModels\MyVar'
```

Comment: Is there a  way to set aliases automatically for all classes in MyModels folder?

Comment: Nope. But you can write some php inside `config/app.php` to hook them up in the aliases array.